# How to initialize a UserDetailsService Bean correctly?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I try to understand a tutorial for Spring Security at Pluralsight.

In this, a UserDetailsService bean is declared.

```
@Bean
UserDetailsService userDetailsService(DataSource dataSource) {

    return new JdbcUserDetailsManager(){
        @Override
        protected List<GrantedAuthority> loadUserAuthorities(String username) {
            return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
        }
    };
}
```

But though i copied the code correctly, i am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in donner.enterprises.godscontest.GodscontestApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required  at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] ...
```

I understood that error, that the DataSource is not initilized or wrong in my declaration.

But this DataSource is working correctly.
 
I have tested it without that Bean, and it worked.
 
In Debugger i see too, that the dataSode is correctly inserted into UserDetailsService, but it still do not start.
How to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Why are you passing the datasource? It's not used in the method

Comment: because it was made so in the tutorial :-) I have tried without, but the same error occurred.

Comment: I don't think that you can use JdbcUserDetailsManger that way. Have a look at https://javainterviewpoint.com/spring-security-jdbcuserdetailsmanager-example/